# What do these permissions number mean?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell. I run the below command in PowerShell.

```
Get-SmbOpenFile -FileId 2251905159197 | Select-Object -Property Permissions
```

And this is the result I got:

```
 Permissions
 1179785
```

And I also got the different result:

```
Permissions
128
```

I am very confused about the number. What does this number mean?

Comment: Others asked that question several years ago (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1028131-powershell-get-smbopenfiles) and were informed that this value is a wrapper for an object that is explained here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/smb/msft-smbopenfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN   However, it was clear that information didn't really make much sense. I would guess it's a code that's supposed to mean something to a computer, and likely to another cmdlet, and not for a human.

Comment: Microsoft never makes anything easy. That larger number (`1179785`) is an AccessMask value. Check out this answer on Stack Exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093376/117259

Comment: Thank you all, I found that this may correspond to the “open mode” column of Shared Folders\Open Files in MMC. I guess 128 means "no access".